# form-actions class similar design in twitter bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

We upgraded to twitter bootstrap 3 (from 2.3.2) and used .form-horizontal forms with the buttons inside .form-actions class in various places. We searched for similar design or alternatives in the new version to no avail.

If there isnt any option whats the new recomended way of putting two or more buttons (in the same line) at the end of an horizontal form?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `.form-action` is removed in bootstrap 3. and you can use a `form-group` to add the buttons at the end of the form.

You can add more buttons to form-group in the same line:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10"> 
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="Save" >
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="Update" >
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you want to have some color effect or background color for the buttons, you must consider that the  form-group has a left and right margin of -15px.

```
<div style="background-color: black; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;" class="form-group">
```

Please see [Bootstrap 3 form and form last row background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206335/bootstrap-3-form-and-form-last-row-background-color/21278939#21278939)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `form-horizontal` class in bs3 also. However, major change is you have to define col width to the label as well as instead of using `form-actions` you can combine more buttons inside `col-x-x` class which used as `controls` in bs2. Please see [this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal).

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Navbar has a similar view

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn">Update</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Or well

```
<div class="well well-sm">
    <button class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn">Update</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Cancel</button>
</div>
```