# Bootstrap 3 form and form last row background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In our forms, we try to:

1. Add a background color to the form and
2. background color to the the last row of the form, which usually contains our buttons.

The problem is that the background color of the last row, is not aligned correctly. You will see that the last row size is exceeded the form width.

Please see:

http://jsfiddle.net/4ThKn/2/

As you noted the black background color is not aligned correctly with the form pink color.

Here is the code, which is same as sample in bootstrap site:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="background-color:pink">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="background-color: black">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Ignore!</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        I am just a sample 
                    </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was each form-group has a left and right margin of -15px, so it's expected that the black part to be 30px wider than the pink part.

To fix it I did as below:

```
<div style="background-color: black; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;" class="form-group">
```

Reference : https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl/issues/20

Answer (score 1):

Invert your divs try this:

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10" style="background: black">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Ignore!</button> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not working. when you maximize your page, there will be an empty line between your form and the last row!